# It's possible to add a shortcode inside Jquery append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress and in my account page shows this shortcode `[woocommerce_my_account]` with has a register form that I need to put on checkout page.

I tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customer_details').append('<div class="login"> [woocommerce_my_account] </div>'); 
});
```

on which the shortcode shows as text.

and this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customer_details').append('<div class="login"> <?php [woocommerce_my_account] ?> </div>'); 
});
```

that shows has a comment `<!--?php [woocommerce_my_account] ?-->`

Any help?

Comment: if you really want to append, you can echo the shortcode out in a hidden div, and then on jquery ready, move the content of that hidden div into the append - This way the shortcode is fired properly, and then jquery just moved the content like it normally would.

Comment: So in php it would be something like 
<div class="login" style=display:none""><?php echo do_shortcode("woocommerce_my_account"); ?></div>
And then in jquery 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customer_details').append('div.login'); 
   $('div.login').show();
}); 
Or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery is running on the client, so your viewers browser. The shortcode lives on your server. Out of the box you don't have access to shortcodes on the client, however you can access them by making an ajax request: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/call-shortcode-in-javascript

Comment: I'm not sure what I should do =/